# Deadlock caused by using NSUserDefaults' synchronize operation GCD queue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

#### Context

We have an event tracking module which would report the collected events in batch when reporting condition triggered. Each event collected is tagged with a unique `event index`. In order to ensure the uniqueness, the work of the `event index` generation is put in a synchronization queue for this module would be called from other threads.

#### Code snippet

```
class EventIndexManager {

fileprivate static let sharedInstance = EventIndexManager()
fileprivate var eventIndexQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.johnkui.EventIndex.SyncQueue")
fileprivate var curEventIndex: UInt64 = 0

static func sharedManager() -> EventIndexManager {
    return sharedInstance
}

func getEventIndex() -> UInt64 {
    eventIndexQueue.sync {
        if self.curEventIndex != 0 {
            self.curEventIndex += 1
        } else {
            if let prevEventIndex = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "event_index") as? UInt64 {
                self.curEventIndex = prevEventIndex + 1
            } else {
                self.curEventIndex = 1
            }
        }
        
        let curEventIndex = self.curEventIndex
        eventIndexQueue.async {
            let eventIndex = self.curEventIndex > curEventIndex ? self.curEventIndex : curEventIndex
            UserDefaults.standard.set(eventIndex, forKey: "event_index")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
    
    return self.curEventIndex
}
}

class EventTask: Taskable {
var event: String
var parameters: [String : Any]
var eventIndex: UInt64

init(event: String, parameters: [String : Any]) {
    self.event = event
    self.parameters = parameters
    self.eventIndex = EventIndexManager.sharedManager().getEventIndex()
    super.init()
}
}


DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let task = EventTask(event: event, parameters: i18nParameters)
                self.tasks.append(task)
            })
```

#### Stack

Here is part of the calling stack

[calling stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6sqb.png)

#### Question

Why is the deadlock caused? What's wrong with my code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You have a cyclic dependency in your code:

1. The initialisation of the shared instance needs an object of `EventIndexManager`.
2. The init function of `EventIndexManager` requires an initialised shared instance.

This can't work, because the variable `sharedManager` is initialised not earlier than after the init function. You should neither access `sharedManager` nor `sharedMananger()` in the init function.

Comment: thx @macmoonshine. Maybe the code format misleading you. In the code snippet, we access the `sharedManager()` in `EventTask` class's init method, not in `EventIndexManager `.